# c# linq returns duplicate data

Tags: c#, linq

I have a this linq query:

```
var fling = (from b in flowering.FlowerViews
                     where ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(flow_name)) && b.FLOWER_NAME == flow_name) || flow_name==""
                     where ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(color_name)) && b.COLOR_NAME == color_name) || color_name == ""
                     where ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(size)) && b.FLOWER_SIZE == size) || size==""
                     where ((low_price!=0) && low_price<= b.FLOWER_PRICE) || low_price==0
                     where ((high_price!=0) && high_price >= b.FLOWER_PRICE)  || high_price==0
                     orderby b.COLOR_NAME
                     select new { b.FLOWER_NAME, b.COLOR_NAME, b.FLOWER_SIZE, b.FLOWER_PRICE, b.CHAR_DESC});
```

my where clauses work for me but when I run a for each loop over the returned values there is duplicate data because b.CHAR_DESC has 3 values to it where all the other return data only have one.  I am wondering if there is a way to get the 3 values assigned to b.CHAR_DESC into a structure that does not cause duplicate b.Flower_name's to show up

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your current output. And a sample of output you would like to get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this post](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/03/25/and-equality-for-all-anonymous-types.aspx) you should be able to call Distinct() for the anonymous type

```
var list = fling.Distinct().ToList();
```

And the compiler will take care of `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` for the anonymous type based on attribute values.

Answer (score 5):

Add `.Distinct()` at the end of your select clause, after the final parenthesis.